# Python - Attribute Error error I can't figure out - 'str' object has no attribute 'get_message_text'

Tags: python, function, class, error-handling, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a set of functions that will implement a caesar cipher by defining new classes, within which is the actual code for the cipher. trying to run it gives me an attribute error:

`original = self.get_message_text()`

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_message_text'

Full code is posted below.

```
import string

class Message(object):

    def __init__(self, text):

        self.message_text = text
        #self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME) - commented out bc irrelevant here


    def get_message_text(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class
    
        Returns: self.message_text
        '''
        return self.message_text

    def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
        letters_lower, letters_upper = string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase
    
    
        new_dict={}
        for letter in letters_upper:
            new_dict[letter] = letters_upper[(letters_upper.index(letter) + shift) % 26]
        for letter in letters_lower:
            new_dict[letter] = letters_lower[(letters_lower.index(letter) + shift) % 26]
    
        return new_dict

    def apply_shift(self, shift):
    
        original = self.get_message_text()
        new = ''
        for letter in original:
            new += (self.build_shift_dict(shift))
        
        #print(new) - a test print
        return new

print(Message.apply_shift('tweLve',12))
```

disclaimer: this is a part of the MIT edx python course but I've checked through all of their notes & forum posts and I am none the wiser. Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: full error message, also I forgot to add the final print statement in the code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ~.spyder-py3\ps5.py:239 in 
> print(Message.apply_shift('tweLve',12))
>
> File ~.spyder-py3\ps5.py:129 in apply_shift
> original = self.get_message_text()
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_message_text'

Comment: it seems you have `self = "some string"` OR you run `apply_shift()` in wrong way and it sends string as first value - and this assign string to `self` and later `self.get_message_text()` works with string.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: show full error message and how your run this code.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the full error message

Comment: you should create instance of class `item = Message("tweLve")` and later run `item.apply_shift(12)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate the class object before running its functions

Full code:

```
import string


class Message(object):

    def __init__(self, text):

        self.message_text = text
        # self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME) - commented out bc irrelevant here

    def get_message_text(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class

        Returns: self.message_text
        '''
        return self.message_text

    def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
        letters_lower, letters_upper = string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase

        new_dict = {}
        for letter in letters_upper:
            new_dict[letter] = letters_upper[(letters_upper.index(letter) + shift) % 26]
        for letter in letters_lower:
            new_dict[letter] = letters_lower[(letters_lower.index(letter) + shift) % 26]

        return new_dict

    def apply_shift(self, shift):

        original = self.get_message_text()
        new = ''
        for letter in original:
            new += (self.build_shift_dict(shift))

        # print(new) - a test print
        return new


if __name__ == '__init__':
    class_obj = Message(text='foo')
    original = class_obj.get_message_text()
    print(original)
```

Comment: Adding the `if __name__`... between the definition and the call to print doesn't have any effect, I still get the same AttributeError in the same place

Comment: You cannot directly call a function inside a class unless you have initiated the class object. As shown above, you may add a line afterwards to print the original text

Answer (score 0):

You should create instance of class and use this instance with `apply_shift()`

```
item = Message("tweLve") 
print( item.apply_shift(12) )
```